# TypeError: cache.writeData is not a function --> apollo-link-state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo

I'm trying to manage local state with apollo-link-state. I've read that you're supposed to set resolvers, defaults and cache with `withClientState()`. So there we go:

```js
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const defaultState = {
    editGraph: {
        __typename: 'EditGraph',
        addNodeForm: 1,
        addRelForm: 'test',
        editGraphForm: false
    }
};

const stateLink = withClientState({
    defaults: defaultState,
    cache
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([
        stateLink,
        new HttpLink(),
    ]),
    cache
});
```

Then pass client to apolloProvider: `<ApolloProvider client={client}>`
But I'm getting the error `TypeError: cache.writeData is not a function`. Which points out this line: `const stateLink = withClientState({`

I want to query and console.log the defaults. But I'm not getting anywhere so far.

From apollo's docs, youtube tutorials and blog articles it's clear that the cache.writeData error shouldn't appear. So why does it here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused by unmet peer dependencies. I installed every dependency I use again and it's working now. So if you want to install and use apollo-link-state in a project you started a while ago, you need to update apollo-link-state its peer dependencies.

Comment: `yarn add apollo-link` fixed my problem

Answer (score 2):

This also tripped me up for a while, to give some more info, apollo-link-state used to path the method onto the apollo cache, but later apollo cache include writeData in it's api.

So if you are using apollo-cache-inmemory make sure you have > 1.1.5.

Here is the relevant PR: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state/pull/164/files

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing `Inmemory cache` from `@apollo/client` you need to do it this way

```
import {
  InMemoryCache
}
```

from `apollo-cache-inmemory` even on apollo version 3